# No tests found while running gtest

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I was making use of gtest to test my c++ project. I followed the steps from [here](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-cmake.html)

Everything went well but when I ran the  `cd build && ctest` command i'm getting the output as `Test project C:/Users/admin/Desktop/last/build No tests were found!!!`

My CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(last)

# GoogleTest requires at least C++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
  googletest
  URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/609281088cfefc76f9d0ce82e1ff6c30cc3591e5.zip
)
# For Windows: Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker settings
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()

add_executable(
  hello_test
  fact.cpp
  header.h
  main.cpp
  testt.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(
  hello_test
  gtest_main
)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(hello_test)
```

Comment: Did you run CMake first?

Comment: ya I did `cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ..` and then `cmake --build build`

Comment: is anything wrong with my CMakeLists file the file which I have are fact.cpp, main.cpp, testt.cpp, header.h

Answer (score 0):

I changed a line in my CMakeLists file

```
add_executable(
  hello_test
  header.h
  main.cpp
  
)
```

And added a line

```
add_test(testt.cpp hello_test)
```

This gave me the output correctly and ran the tests